# Error when deploying Azure Function to KEDA using func deploy

Tags: kubernetes, azure-functions

Had created a simple hello world Azure Functions QueueTrigger and when tried to deploy using the below command, got the highlighted error

```
$ sudo func kubernetes deploy --name myfunction --namespace functions-ns --registry myregistry
```

> error: unable to recognize "STDIN": no matches for kind "ScaledObject"
>   in version "keda.k8s.io/v1alpha1"

Answer (score 2):

Running the below command resolved the issue:

`func kubernetes install --namespace {a namespace}`

More details [here](https://github.com/kedacore/keda/wiki/Using-Azure-Functions-with-Keda-and-Osiris).